# Robotic voice with Web Audio API when slowing down tempo

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, bass

I use Web Audio API in my website.
Lets say I have this code:

```
var audioContext = new Audiocontext()
var audio = new Audio()
audio.src = "someaudiofile.wav"
var mediaSourceNode = audioContext.CreateMediaElementSource(audio)
mediaSourceNode.connect(audioContext.destination)

audio.playbackRate = 0.5
```

When I set the 0.5 playbackRate, the audio becomes a little robotic/distorted.

We also have an old .Net based audio player based on Bass .Net library, which fix this issue by setting the property Bass_attrib_tempo_option_sequence_ms according to the new tempo, but I didnt find a corresponding property in Web Audio api.

Does someone have any experience with this? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As you already found out the AudioBufferSourceNode just resamples the audio to slow it down or to speed it up. This behavior is defined by the [spec](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#playback-AudioBufferSourceNode).

I'm not familiar with the source code of the Bass .Net library but from looking at the options it exposes I would guess it uses an implementation of the [SOLA algorithm](https://www.surina.net/article/time-and-pitch-scaling.html) under the hood. Luckily there is also an implementation in JavaScript ([soundtouchjs](https://github.com/cutterbl/SoundTouchJS)) which will hopefully give you similar results as the aforementioned .Net library.